# Dynamically generate pie chart in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am having 3 charts in my web page. I want to represent data from table in pie chart. First chart displays data which has highest msg_id(column of table), second shows data of second highest msg_id and third shows of third highest msg_id. I want to do it with simple asp.net chart. In short want to know how to bind chart programmatically with data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's link to one example that appears to fit into your requirements: http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/PieChart/PieChart.aspx